# Calculator for time complexity of recursion functions

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, computer-science

Is there an online tool that returns the time complexity of recursion functions?

For instance when I enter : T(n) = T(n/2) +n
I'd like to get: θ(n)

I tried using wolframalpha but it doesn't return the above result I was looking for.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%29%3Dg%28n%2F2%29%2Bn

Comment: You can do it in Mathematica: https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/asymptotics/find-the-computational-complexity.html?product=mathematica

Comment: Thank you @PaulR
Do you know if there's a free online tool for this?

Comment: Not that I know of - maybe ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I found it.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/134917/8278)
One needs to click on "Show Weaker Bound" button. See attached

[image]